# Netbeans 7 and undocked editor window: Why won't files open in the undocked window?

Tags: netbeans, editor

I can't seem to find an answer to this one, so I thought I would check here. I recently upgraded from Netbeans 6.9.1 to 7.0. In 6.9.1, if I undocked the editor window (for use on a second monitor) and then double-clicked a file in the Projects view, the file would open in the opened undocked editor. In 7.0, it opens in the empty section of the rest of the docked IDE, and I have to drag it to the undocked editor. I don't remember changing a setting in 6.9.1 to turn on the desired behaviour. Sounds like a small thing, but it gets annoying if you are opening and closing files frequently.

Anyone know how to remedy this?

Hopefully it is not too obvious, but if it is, I will eat my humble pie and you can return to your regularly scheduled day...

Thanks!

Comment: No quick fix from here it seems. I will see if I can get any info from the Netbeans folks, and answer this myself if I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else was having this issue, it was fixed in the 7.0.1 update for Netbeans. I have installed that version, and now everything works as correctly as it used to, which is fantastic because undocked code windows seems to be the best solution for multiple monitors in my experience.